# Pandas- Set element of Pivot table to variable

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a Pivot table named `table1` that looks like:

```
                       Volume
Site TripDate                
003l 1990-06-10   2354.043820
     1991-07-26   2745.673779
     1993-10-08  22789.790846
     1994-11-20  23072.306665
     1995-04-24  25203.740194
     1996-02-13  16505.985301
     1996-04-15   8257.426317
     1996-09-12   9148.369265
     1997-02-13  10014.168593
     1997-04-20  11154.686365
     1997-08-23  13064.444117
     1997-11-06  13704.596573
     1998-04-15  14358.140459
     1999-05-04  18100.457859
     2000-03-17  22910.600843
     2000-06-01    617.621794
     2001-10-05    882.738323
016l 1990-06-10    962.070643
     1991-07-26    761.409178
     1993-10-08    475.038362
     1994-11-20    312.339596
     1995-04-24  11569.523232
     1996-02-13  15272.175019
     1996-04-15  13542.057394
     1996-09-12  14556.930737
     1997-02-13  18905.265710
     1997-04-20  19832.509861
```

I am interested in Calculating percent volume for each site using the earliest volume calculation as the "theoretical value" to normalize the data. For each site, is there a way to define a variable for the earliest volume calculation (i.e. 1990-06-10) directly from the pivot table?

An example formula for %Volume would be:

```
%Volume=(V_survey-V_1990)/(V_1990)
```

I have tired to subset based on the level one index using:

```
test = table1[table1[['TripDate']]==1990-06-10]
```

but, it throws the following error:

```
KeyError: "['TripDate'] not in index"
```

If I check the names of the indices using `list(table1.index.names)` it returns:

```
['Site', 'TripDate']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to my problem, although I am sure there is a much more elegant solution.

In developing my solution, I created a pivot table with the earliest date using:

```
query2 = query1[query1.TripDate=='1990-06-10']
```

where `query1` is a subset of my original data file.

I then created a piviot table is a way similar to `table1` and `table2` using:

```
table3 = pd.pivot_table(query2,values=['Volume'], index=['Site','TripDate'], aggfunc=np.sum)
table3 = table3.rename(columns = {'Volume':'Early_Vol'})
```

I can then merge `table1` and table3` using:

```
merge = pd.merge(table1.reset_index(),table3.reset_index(),on=['Site'],how='left')
```

And after a little formatting I am left with my desired output:

```
    Site   TripDate        Volume    Early_Vol
0   003l 1990-06-10   2354.043820  2354.043820
1   003l 1991-07-26   2745.673779  2354.043820
2   003l 1993-10-08  22789.790846  2354.043820
3   003l 1994-11-20  23072.306665  2354.043820
4   003l 1995-04-24  25203.740194  2354.043820
5   003l 1996-02-13  16505.985301  2354.043820
6   003l 1996-04-15   8257.426317  2354.043820
7   003l 1996-09-12   9148.369265  2354.043820
8   003l 1997-02-13  10014.168593  2354.043820
9   003l 1997-04-20  11154.686365  2354.043820
10  003l 1997-08-23  13064.444117  2354.043820
11  003l 1997-11-06  13704.596573  2354.043820
12  003l 1998-04-15  14358.140459  2354.043820
13  003l 1999-05-04  18100.457859  2354.043820
14  003l 2000-03-17  22910.600843  2354.043820
15  003l 2000-06-01    617.621794  2354.043820
16  003l 2001-10-05    882.738323  2354.043820
17  016l 1990-06-10    962.070643   962.070643
18  016l 1991-07-26    761.409178   962.070643
19  016l 1993-10-08    475.038362   962.070643
20  016l 1994-11-20    312.339596   962.070643
21  016l 1995-04-24  11569.523232   962.070643
22  016l 1996-02-13  15272.175019   962.070643
23  016l 1996-04-15  13542.057394   962.070643
24  016l 1996-09-12  14556.930737   962.070643
25  016l 1997-02-13  18905.265710   962.070643
26  016l 1997-04-20  19832.509861   962.070643
27  016l 1997-08-23  20914.494534   962.070643
```